# C-S-PageUp and C-S-PageDown keymappings stopped working in vim

Tags: linux, vim, arch-linux, xfce4-terminal

I have these lines in my `.vimrc` which let me quickly move tabs around:

```
nmap <C-S-PageUp> :-tabmove<CR>
nmap <C-S-PageDown> :+tabmove<CR>
```

I tested using other commands instead, and it refuses to work with them as well.

Changing the keys does make it work, but they're part of my muscle memory by now.

This was all fine until I recently did a system update (`pacman -Syu`). The upgrade made the following changes:

- `vim-runtime` 8.2.4106-1 -> 8.2.4651-1
- `gvim` 8.2.4106-1 -> 8.2.4651-1
- `xfce4-terminal` 0.8.10-2 -> 1.0.1-1

Since the vim changes were in the patch version only, I suspect that the xfce4-terminal upgrade messed things up. But how can I confirm this? And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Just after posting, I found [a bug report](https://gitlab.xfce.org/apps/xfce4-terminal/-/issues/186) on xfce4-terminal stating:

> This has also been reported in [#24](https://gitlab.xfce.org/apps/xfce4-terminal/-/issues/24). It's a byproduct of rewriting the shortcus code to deal with a bunch of deprecated things. It will be fixed in 1.0.2 (which I will release soon, I'm just waiting to see if any other issues come up).

Actually I can just disable those shortcuts on xfce4-terminal because I'm not using them. I changed these lines in `~/.config/xfce4/terminal/accels.scm`:

```
(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/terminal-window/move-tab-right" "") ; "<Primary><Shift>Page_Down")
(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/terminal-window/move-tab-left" "") ; "<Primary><Shift>Page_Up")
(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/terminal-window/next-tab" "") ; "<Primary>Page_Up"
(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/terminal-window/prev-tab" "") ; "<Primary>Page_Up"
```

After restarting xfce4-terminal (all windows, since they share a process) I can now use these keys inside the terminal again.